# Django Rest Framework: Response with additional data besides the default model fields, where the additional data needs to come from sql query

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm a new to django and django rest framework and trying to build an app which should communicate with a mobile phone.

Currently I'm trying to create a response which should include not only the requested model's fields but add some additional data, which should be calculated first from another model.

I have 2 models in my code:
1. Bill
2. BillComment (has foreign key to Bill model)

This is a many(BillComment) to one(Bill) relationship.
And I need to append in the response the number of comments in BillComment table related to the specific bill.

This is my current code, which is **NOT** running:

**models.py**

```
class BillComment(models.Model):

    bill    = models.ForeignKey(Bill)    
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    responsed_to = models.ForeignKey('rest_api.BillComment', null=True, blank=True) 
    date    = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.bill, self.user, self.responsed_to, self.date, self.content)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_comments_count(self, foo):
        comments_co = BillComment.objects.filter(bill=data.bill).count()
        return comments_co;

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('id', 'subject', 'date', 'description', 'status', 'parliament_member', 'comments_count')
```

As you can see, I'm trying to response with additional parameter.
I need some how to read the id of the requested bill row so I can filter all BillComment rows where their 'bill' field (which is a foreign key) is pointing to the same bill which is serialized.

How can I do that?

Maybe I have more appropriate solution then using SerializerMethodField, please advice me how to do this properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but do you want the count so you can paginate properly?  If so, you could just start retrieving `BillComment`'s.  It will have a total count, `PAGE_SIZE` number of comments, and a link to the next chunk of comments.  Alternatively, you can easily get a list of _all_ the comments for a _specific_ `Bill` by adding a `related_name` field to your `BillComment.bill` field:  `bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, related_name='bill_comments').  Then in your `BillSerializer`'s `Meta.fields` statement, add `bill_comments' and it will retrieve them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. The mobile client will need to show how many comments exist for the specific bill. The mobile app should request a specific bill object, and I need add some extra information into the JSON. I don't need to serialize the comments their self and it is not related to pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is only one switch away from being correct, as you have almost everything set up properly. A [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) passes in the current object being serialized as the first parameter to the method, which in your case is the `Bill` object being serialized.

So your `get_comments_count` method would just need to look like

```
def get_comments_count(self, bill):
    comments_co = BillComment.objects.filter(bill=bill).count()
    return comments_co
```

And everything should work as expected.

You can make this quicker by modifying your queryset to use [`Count` annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#id7) instead of manually [calling `.count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#count), which will save you *n* extra queries, and improve the performance at the same time. All you need to do is add `.annotate(comments_count=Count('billcomment_set'))` to the end of your current queryset for the view, and then add the `comments_count` field to your serializer as an `IntegerField`.

```
queryset = Bill.objects.all().annotate(comments_count=Count('billcomment_set'))
```

And your serializer would become

```
class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('id', 'subject', 'date', 'description', 'status', 'parliament_member', 'comments_count')
```

This is because the `comments_count` property will be added to each object returned by the queryset, and the serializer will serialize it like any other field.